# Retrive date from DateTime Object using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have an array as follows, and now I need to retrieve the date value from DateTime Object using PHP.

```
Array(
[0] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2013-08-12 00:00:00
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => Europe/Amsterdam
    )
```

Can any one please let me know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: so just: `???[0]['date']`

Comment: I tried the same, but that doesn't work for me @Dagon

Comment: this link solved my question

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135830/echo-an-array-date-time-object-in-timestamp-format

Solution:
`echo $date['0']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

@rizier123 : my question is not duplicate with respect to your assignment. please change it over to my link provided.